# Creating objects from array to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of object like this

```
[
    {"id": "1", "name": "test"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "test2"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "test3"}
]
```

I want to convert it to object list this

```
{
  "1": {"name": "test"},
  "2": {"name": "test2"},
  "3": {"name": "test3"},
}
```

Comment: *"Creating objects from array to json object"* ***sigh*** It's not a "json object." It's just an object. JSON is a *textual* notation for data interchange.

Comment: Why in first place didn't you generate an object instead of an array of objects? Maybe this array comes from any third party script but i have to ask it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(m,o){ m[o.id]={name:o.name}; return m }, {});
```

Side note : please be sure to read and try to understand T.J.'s comment about [JSON](http://json.org)

Comment: @ OP - Note that `Array#reduce` requires a modern browser or a shim; if you need to support older browsers like IE8, search for "es5 shim" for options.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right but isn't it time we stop telling that ? After all even gmail stopped supporting IE9 long ago (this is a question, not a critic of the comment).

Comment: @ dystroy: My take is that when [6%](http://goo.gl/V7JZHm) to [21%](http://goo.gl/mnJ1OU) of people globally are still using a browser (IE8), it's still relevant and important. Despite the XP deadline having passed, I suspect we're stuck with IE8 a while longer. I can't afford for even 6% of my users to have my site fail with a random script error. And the note is easy to add. Now of course, the only stats that *really* matter are the stats for one's own site...